# Converting WKT to WKB in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, wkt, wkb

I have a table called `areas_map` with two columns `a_id (bigint)` and `geom (geometry(MultiPolygon, 4326))`.

Table "public.areas_map"
Column  |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default
----------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
gid      | integer                     |           | not null |
a_id     | bigint                      |           |          |
gtype    | smallint                    |           |          |
geom     | geometry(MultiPolygon,4326) |           |          |
mod_op   | character(1)                |           |          |
mod_date | timestamp without time zone |           |          |
Indexes:
"areas_map_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (gid)
"idx_areas_map_geom" gist (geom)
"idx_areas_map_a_id" btree (a_id)
Triggers:
trig_mod_op_date BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON areas_map FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE add_mod_op_date()

I have another table called `areas` with columns `a_id_1 (character varying)` and `wkt` to insert in the above table, `areas_map`. I need to convert the wkt geometry to wkb geometry in order to put it in the 'areas_map'.

These are the columns in the 'areas' table in my database.

Table "public.areas" Column | Type | Collation | Nullable | Default --------------+-------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------- ogc_fid | integer | | not null | nextval('areas_ogc_fid_seq'::regclass) a_id_1 | character varying | | | wkt | character varying | | | wkb_geometry | geometry | | | Indexes: "areas_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (ogc_fid) "areas_wkb_geometry_geom_idx" gist (wkb_geometry)

And this is data in the table 'areas'.

ogc_fid |    a_id_1    |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             wkt                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 wkb_geometry
---------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 | 3002618658 | MULTIPOLYGON(((-76.5473560619672 42.9413419720012,-76.5461994270791 42.9408894029933,-76.5428849220592 42.9424413310329,-76.540085618445 42.9435130207937,-76.5403432456807 42.9445933354756,-76.5417136457824 42.9446447959923,-76.5423695540135 42.9449534586902,-76.5424515359008 42.9454507456148,-76.5446238177076 42.9456536187894,-76.5449061034313 42.9473752994633,-76.5465216192731 42.9473555320693,-76.5464451670431 42.9465415450345,-76.547964643124 42.9465042162103,-76.5475477862325 42.9444728204718,-76.5473560619672 42.9413419720012))) |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
2 | 3003264375 | MULTIPOLYGON(((-118.20883035065 33.8744540214534,-118.208788426448 33.8811453764129,-118.214318573149 33.8811626720137,-118.213868789377 33.8764587738789,-118.214025554548 33.8755041061261,-118.214192790618 33.8749920466446,-118.213910539173 33.8744626447363,-118.20883035065 33.8744540214534)))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      | 010600000001000000010300000001000000080000000E9DF9795D8D5DC0C0FFFF1BEEEF404028D821CA5C8D5DC0865B275FC9F040406CA63F65B78D5DC09E603DF0C9F040409900B806B08D5DC0130D15CD2FF04040AF523D98B28D5DC0A4A9BF8410F0404092AFAD55B58D5DC0A14C48BDFFEF40402381D4B5B08D5DC0A85B5664EEEF40400E9DF9795D8D5DC0C0FFFF1BEEEF4040
(2 rows)

I tried the following sql command but it kept giving me error.

```
INSERT INTO areas_map(a_id, geom)
SELECT a_id_1, ST_AsBinary(ST_GeomFromText(wkt)) AS geom
FROM areas WHERE a_id_1=CAST(a_id_1 as bigint);
```

I really appreciate your help.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the error it gives?

Comment: Can you also post your table schema (`create table ...`)

Comment: This is the error I am getting.   ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = bigint
LINE 3: FROM areas WHERE qid_1=CAST(qid_1 as bigint);
                                    ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: This is my data.

Comment: qid_1         wkt
3002618658 MULTIPOLYGON(((-76.5473560619672 42.9413419720012,-76.5461994270791 42.9408894029933,-76.5428849220592 42.9424413310329,-76.540085618445 42.9435130207937,-76.5403432456807 42.9445933354756,-76.5417136457824 42.9446447959923,-76.5423695540135 42.9449534586902,-76.5424515359008 42.9454507456148,-76.5446238177076 42.9456536187894,-76.5449061034313 42.9473752994633,-76.5465216192731 42.9473555320693,-76.5464451670431 42.9465415450345,-76.547964643124 42.9465042162103,-76.5475477862325 42.9444728204718,-76.5473560619672 42.9413419720012)))

Comment: I don't know what qid_1 is, it is not described in the question

Comment: INSERT INTO areas_map(a_id, geom)
SELECT a_id_1, ST_AsBinary(ST_GeomFromText(wkt)) AS geom
FROM areas WHERE a_id_1=CAST(a_id_1 as bigint);

Comment: Table "public.areas_map"
  Column  |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default
----------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 gid      | integer                     |           | not null |
 a_id     | bigint                      |           |          |
 geom     | geometry(MultiPolygon,4326) |           |          |                                                        This is the table I have in posstgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your error, I think that the query you wish is:

```
INSERT INTO areas_map(a_id, geom)
VALUES (3002618658, ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOLYGON(((-76.5473560619672 42.9413419720012,-76.5461994270791 42.9408894029933,-76.5428849220592 42.9424413310329,-76.540085618445 42.9435130207937,-76.5403432456807 42.9445933354756,-76.5417136457824 42.9446447959923,-76.5423695540135 42.9449534586902,-76.5424515359008 42.9454507456148,-76.5446238177076 42.9456536187894,-76.5449061034313 42.9473752994633,-76.5465216192731 42.9473555320693,-76.5464451670431 42.9465415450345,-76.547964643124 42.9465042162103,-76.5475477862325 42.9444728204718,-76.5473560619672 42.9413419720012)))'), 4326))
```

you just have to insert your data into the table

Comment: Can you please explain what you did differently so other can understand why your solution works.

Comment: It gave me the following error when I put the cast in the select part                                          ERROR:  Geometry SRID (0) does not match column SRID (4326)

Comment: try the edited answer, I added a conversion to the proper srid

Comment: It still gave me the same error.                                                                                                  Geometry SRID (0) does not match column SRID (4326)

Comment: @Lily, I cannot reproduce your error, can you give a reproducible example (`create table` for `areas` and `areas_map` and the `insert` clause to areas)  so we can sort this out?

Comment: Table "public.areas_map"
  Column  |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default
----------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 gid      | integer                     |           | not null |
 vid      | bigint                      |           |          |
 gtype    | smallint                    |           |          |
 geom     | geometry(MultiPolygon,4326) |           |          |
 mod_op   | character(1)                |           |          |
 mod_date | timestamp without time zone |           |          |

Comment: @lily can you please also post table `areas` ?

Comment: I have posted the table areas in the answer box.

Comment: 3002618658 is the first a_id_1 and 3003264375 is the second a_id_1.

Comment: @lily what you posted was content and not a table. So I am assuming this is data that comes from somewhere else that is not the database.

Comment: Table "public.areas"
    Column    |       Type        | Collation | Nullable |                Default
--------------+-------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------
 ogc_fid      | integer           |           | not null | nextval('areas_ogc_fid_seq'::regclass)
 a_id         | character varying |           |          |
 wkt          | character varying |           |          |
 wkb_geometry | geometry          |           |          |
Indexes:
    "areas_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (ogc_fid)
    "areas_wkb_geometry_geom_idx" gist (wkb_geometry)

Comment: I  have included my table (areas) from my database in the question box.

Comment: When I tried to insert the data in the table it gave me this error.    ERROR:  null value in column "gid" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, 3002618658, null, 0106000020E6100000010000000103000000010000000F000000A85AB8E10723..., I, 2021-09-13 23:21:45.47066).

Comment: @NuLo When I tried to insert my data in the table it gave me this error. ERROR: null value in column "gid" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains (null, 3002618658, null, 0106000020E6100000010000000103000000010000000F000000A85AB8E10723..., I, 2021-09-13 23:21:45.47066).

Comment: You have to decide the value you want on the column gid, you haven't explained what it is

Comment: In the areas_map table in the database, the gid is integer and has index as
    "areas_map_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (gid)

Comment: What should the value of gid be for the row that is being inserted in the example?

Comment: I just put 1 for gid and the query worked but I have more data to insert and the gid column is supposed to be an automatic serial number.

Comment: Then you have to change that column in the db's table to be a serial

Comment: @NuLo I have multiple data to insert in the table, is there an easier way to do so instead of inserting it one by one or a few at a time?

Comment: There are many ways but that depends on how you have the original data you want to import

Comment: I have 375 same kind of data, geom in wkt and their respective id numbers, in a table called 'areas' and I created a table called 'areas_map'                                                 CREATE TABLE areas_map(a_id bigint,geom geometry(MultiPolygon,4326));                                   I want to put the 375 records in wkb format in 'areas_map'.